# Is there a timeframe for the Apple C modules coming to Xcode toolchain?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, module

There’s a [presentation by Doug Gregor](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-11/Gregor-Modules.pdf) from Apple about a new modules feature in C, C++ and Objective-C. It feels obvious that this feature is going to end up in the Xcode toolchain. Is there a roadmap, some timeframe or at least some additional information?

Comment: Sure: too late to be adopted widely, too soon for not making the transition a nightmare.

Comment: I don’t care about adoption that much if Xcode and the standard frameworks support the feature and I can take advantage of it in my own code. As for the transition, there seem to be some nice backward compatibility features. No idea how they’re going to work in practice.

Comment: my idea is that they won't. I'm a big fan of backwards compatibility and standards and Apple doesn't seem to respect either one.

Comment: @H2CO3: you are being pessimistic though, because the C++ committee **cares a lot** about backward compatibility and therefore modules will just never make it into the Standard without full-on backward compatibility feature. The presentation is extremely explicit about how module maps will be used to integrate existing header systems in, for example, so that you can use modules even with 3rd party software that was packaged the "traditional" way.

Comment: This is an interesting question - thanks for asking it. I'm excited to see Apple make improvements to programming in C(++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is all speculation*

It will probably appear in clang before it is officially adopted into the C++ standard. How else will Apple (or anyone) get experience in how well/poorly modules work without an implementation?

Whether or not Apple will ship an Xcode with this feature enabled is unclear.

The next version of the C++ standard will not appear before 2014 at the earliest.

H2CO3: I agree that Apple is not a big fan of backwards compatibility. IMHO they see it as nice, but not necessary. When the benefits (as they see them) outweigh the costs, then they are willing to break backwards compatibility.

However, from looking at Doug's talk, this (modules) looks like an addition, rather than a change. I don't think that Apple is looking to suddenly break every bit of existing C/C++ code on their platform with this.

Comment: [It's already in Clang](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/test/Modules/). Of course the draft proposals for it aren't complete yet. I also recall hearing a talk that they deliberately used annoying names at this point in the development cycle to ensure that they don't become fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The next C++ standard is currently referred to as C++14, indicating a 2014 release target. There's also no indication it will be Apple's version, Clang seems to be doing a bit of development on it, there is even [a branch with modules support](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/test/Modules/), of course its early development.

Apparently C++14 is only really a bugfix so no idea if a big feature like modules will make it in, although work on it began before C++11 so it's possible. Garbage collection would be in a similar boat (although that is more complex).

Then there is also the next one on, C++17.